# Passing a variable to a view called in a TabBar

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, tabbar

I have a problem in time to pass a variable to a view.

I have three views:

**ListagemReceitas** - View with TableView

**BlocoReceita** - View with TabBar

**CapaReceita** - View with data to be displayed

The flow is this:

- At the click of tableView to the view I call the view ListagemReceitas BlocoReceita
- The view CapaReceita which is linked to item 1 of the tabbar, and is displayed whenever the view BlocoReceita is called, needs to receive a variable to locate the information to be displayed;

When I call the view at the click of BlocoReceita tableView ListagemReceitas in view, I go directly to the view CapaReceita variable with the code below:

```
Receita_Capa_iPhone detailViewController = * [[Receita_Capa_iPhone alloc] initWithNibName: @ "Receita_Capa_iPhone" bundle: nil];
NSDictionary * dict = [arrCanapes objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
[detailViewController setCodigo: [dict objectForKey: @ "code"]];
```

Only when the view is loaded CapaReceita (viewWillAppear), data is retrieved as null.

I've tried to pass the code to view BlocoReceita, and it viewWillAppear pass code to view CapaReceita, but to no avail.

I made a test call directly at the click of view CapaReceita tableView ListagemReceitas in view, and then it works. But when I call this view and BlocoReceita CapaReceita automatically loads the view, then the data is as void.

Could someone tell me what might be wrong? If you have any specific method for this?

I call the view BlocoReceita with the code:

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController: receitaViewController animated: YES];
```

because as it has a TabBar independent of the TabBar ListagemReceitas view, not given to do using "pushViewController."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put an NSLog statement after the:

NSDictionary * dict = [arrCanapes objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"dict = %@",dict);  // Add this

I bet you will find that the dictionary isn't getting instantiated properly.